# Is there a way to store hashed passwords for php mysqli login?

Tags: php, mysqli

I usually do

```
$password = "password";
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", $password, "database");
```

Is there a way to give mysqli a hashed password instead of having to save the plaintext form stored in my script? Is there a good practice to avoid having plaintext passwords around my script? Is this safe

I get it won't be 100% proof but it does make it slightly more cumbersome to not have the plaintext available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope; that would defy the point in using password hashing in the first place. If you could log in with the hashed password, then the hashed password would essentially *be* your password.

You could encrypt it, but the key for decryption would also have to be stored somewhere, so you'd merely be obfuscating the password, not protecting it. Anyone who *wants* it can easily find it, if he has access to your script files.

Ultimately, you'll have to place some trust in the security of your server's own filesystem. Your best bet is just to make sure it's stored outside the document root and is not readable by any user/group on the server who doesn't need to read it.

Comment: is there at least a better way to store this rather than in plaintext?

Comment: I think thats the best way, I'm thinking of storing it out of the root filesystem in a weird eval like encrypted form, not 100% but its a bit tougher to get to

Comment: @Akshat Frankly, I wouldn't bother with the obfuscation; it won't deter a serious attacker. Besides, if he has access to your filesystem to the point he can access the script, all bets are off.

Comment: Exactly what @WillVousden mentioned. If they can see your script they can see what the password is or where you are calling it from.

Comment: @Akshat not only this, but think of the programmers that will work on the project after you. They will look for you with a knife and try to perform an adult circumcision.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no. Whatever is sent as the password *is* the password. Even if you were to create a small function to hash your password, you'd still have to have the password in plain text. Even still, that hashed password becomes your password (as you would've setup in MySQL) therefor it's still plain text.

Since PHP is a server-side script no one can see this password nor is it ever transferred to the client so it cannot be intercepted. I'd recommend a hard to guess password and make sure your scripts are protected from MySQL injection so no one can access your database through that route.